# Which is correct: "the variable X" or "variable X" or "the X variable"?

Tags: articles

I'm writing a description of my code. X is one of many variables.

Which version should I use to refer to X:

- "the variable X" or
- "variable X" or
- "the X variable" ?

Does the same rule applies to "method", "array" etc.?

Answer (score 2):

My bet is on

> the variable X

"The X variable" seems rather cloggy and I wouldn't use it personally.

Wikipedia has a similar understanding. Here an excerpt:

> In mathematical terms, **the dependent variable y** represents the value of a function of x. To simplify formulas, it is often useful to use the same symbol for **the dependent variable y** and the function mapping x onto y.